# Check if a file contains another file

Tags: c++, windows, file, header, portable-executable

I'm talking about Windows PE files.
Is there a way to check if one file contains another?
I mean... What if I merge two programs like this

```
MZ header 1st program
PE header 1st program
.
.
. all the sections from 1st program
.
MZ header 2nd program
PE header 2nd program
.
.
. all the sections from 2nd program
.
```

into one runable program? Of course, only the first one would run.

Comment: You want a command line tool that searches for a binary inside of another binary?

Comment: What is your goal exactly ? I can't think of a legitimate (and not suspicious) reason for merging two exectuables files like that.

Comment: I'm looking for C/C++ solution and need it for bachelor's thesis about malware research.

Comment: @ere samuel wants to detect such a file and not make one

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: And I never stated the opposite ;) I was just wondering on which occasions you may encounter such merged files and what was the context of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you'd first want to get the offset and size information about the **last** section of the PE file(`IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER`). Once you have this information, you can read the chunk after (offset + size), and if it matches with another PE format (MZ magic number), then it would *suggest* that there is a second file appended to the first.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful, but I've encountered a problem - it works on release build, not on debug build. What could possibly be the cause of this? I haven't found any information about what comes after PE Sections. I thought sections were at the very end. Could it be some debug data? Aren't they supposed to be in debug directory?

Comment: It could as well be, not necessary debug symbol database but something else that assists in debugging, or something completely different. It can really be anything...